# Seperating output as variable

Tags: equation-solving, vector

I have an output like this:

```
out = {{{x1, y1, z1}, {a1, b1, c1}}, {{x2, y2, z2}, {a2, b2, c2}}, {{x3, y3, z3}, {a3, b3, c3}}};
```

Now want to save this output in two different variables `A` and `B` so that I can use it as independent variable

```
A = {{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}, {x3, y3, z3}}
```

and

```
B = {{a1, b1, c1}, {a2, b2, c2}, {a3, b3, c3}}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `A = out[[All, 1]]` and `B = out[[All, 2]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{A, B} = Transpose[{{{x1, y1, z1}, {a1, b1, c1}}, {{x2, y2, z2}, {a2, 
    b2, c2}}, {{x3, y3, z3}, {a3, b3, c3}}}]
```

`Transpose` flips the list, and then you can directly assign `A` and `B` to the two columns in the result. `Transpose` is very powerful for this sort of manipulation, and it can transpose between several different levels of a list, so I'd recommend checking the documentation on it for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and kind suggestions.

Comment: @Bikash If this answers your question sufficiently, please consider accepting the answer.